# Jquery Flot-Chart: point position for dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I've just started using flot and I'm already clueless how I'll get the points on the right date. First I thought it might be a problem with the daytime, if so.. how do I handle it?

```
var data = [
    [gd(1, 1, 2014), 125],
    [gd(2, 1, 2014), 101],
    [gd(3, 1, 2014), 118],
    [gd(4, 1, 2014), 109],
    [gd(5, 1, 2014), 131],
    [gd(6, 1, 2014), 129],
    [gd(7, 1, 2014), 115]
];

var dataset =
[{
    label: "Label",
    data: data,
    color: "#e5a836",
    points: { 
        fillColor: "#a27c36",
        show: true
    },
    lines: { show: true }
}];
var options = {
    grid: {
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    },
    yaxis: {
        color: "black"
    },
    xaxis: {
        position: "bottom",
        color: "black",
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [1, "day"],
        timeformat: "%d.%m.%Y"
    }
}
```

Made a quick review:
http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/4276/

Comment: SOLVED. Fixed the issue by adding an hour because the time was calculated in UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your `gd()` function:

```
return Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day);
```

Flot uses UTC by default but `new Date()` gives you local time by default.